# Replicate a vector to a list

Tags: r, list

Given vector, e.g., `v <-c(1,2,3)`, how to get a list for a given number of replication( e.g.,100 ) such that

```
  >foo(v, 100) 


        [[1]]
        [1] 1 2 3


        [[2]]
        [1] 1 2 3

        [[3]]
        [1] 1 2 3

        ......

        [[100]]
        [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: `rep(list(v), 100)`

Comment: @RonakShah You leave massive points on the table every day with these comments, many of which deserve to be full-fledged answers.  But why?

Comment: I appreciate @Ronak Shah again and again today !! Thank you, your rapid answer helps me, thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sometimes, I am not sure if it is a duplicate or not. So I post as a comment so OP can carry on with what they are working on while I search for duplicate and if I don't find one I post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for my low level questions... Thanks @Ronak Shah....

Comment: nothing is low-level @CamfordOxbridge , we all have been there :) By asking these questions you are saving future readers time.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. What I want to say you is Thank you. You helps my developing package. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is `replicate` with `simplify = FALSE` which would return output as list

```
replicate(100, v, simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will do it

```
rep(list(v), 100)
```